# sh: dot: command not found + doxygen + Lion

Tags: doxygen, graphviz, dot

- MacOS version: 10.7.2 (Lion)
- Doxygen version: 1.7.5.1
- Graphviz version: 2.29

Doxygen configuration:

```
DOT_PATH = ../../../../Applications/Contents/MacOS/Graphviz
HAVE_DOT = YES
SHORT_NAMES = YES
```

From the log console, first line it gives a warning:

> warning: the dot tool could not be found at ../../../../Applications/Contents/MacOS/Graphviz

I have tried various combinations but the warning does not go away, although it does generate the images.

> Generating dot graphs using 9 parallel threads...
>   Running dot for graph 1/68
>   sh: dot: command not found
>
> Problems running dot: exit code=127, command='dot', arguments='"/Users/salilk/Documents/project/DoxygenDocs/html/a00033.dot" -Tpng -o "/Users/salilk/Documents/project/DoxygenDocs/html/a00033.png"'

In the html directory the .dot files have been generated but no .png.

**Now if I execute the same command from the Terminal the .png file gets generated and is displayed in its .html file.**

Another error from the console is:

> error: problems opening map file /Users/salilk/Documents/A2O Collaborate/DoxygenDocs/html/a00032.map for inclusion in the docs!
>   If you installed Graphviz/dot after a previous failing run, try deleting the output directory and rerun doxygen.

Is this related to the above problem ?

I have used Doxygen before on a Windows machine and didn't have these errors, do we need to do any configurations specific for Mac?

Comment: I would expect dot to be installed in /usr/local/bin/dot. Did you check that? and if it is there use DOT_PATH=/usr/local/bin/dot

Comment: Yes its there and now DOT_PATH = /usr/local/bin/dot. Still i get this warning - warning: the dot tool could not be found at /usr/local/bin/dot and errors same as above.

Comment: is the path really /usr/local/bin/dot or is dot already the executable? In that case, try /usr/local/bin

Comment: @arne setting DOT_PATH = /usr/local/bin works, Thank you.

Comment: I had the exact same problem. Fresh install of Doxygen and graphviz, turned on dot graphs and the same error messages in the log. Typing the dot command in terminal created the png file from the dot file, and 'which dot' showed /usr/local/bin. Checking path (in terminal) also showed /usr/local/bin in path. BUT - I suspect that Doxygen did not for some reason use this path, because when I modified the Doxygen file for my project and set DOT PATH = /usr/local/bin, the graphs were correctly created.

Answer (score 25):

Set the DOT_PATH to: `/usr/local/bin`

[image]

Comment: Solved also my problem in OS x El Captain, Eclipse Mars and Eclox plug-in!

Comment: If you don't know where your "dot" binary file is, try running the command "dot -v" in your console; The information that appears (provided you do have Graphviz installed) includes the "libdir" full path, and the "bin" directory that you're looking for will be at the same path as the "lib" folder in that path.

Answer (score 1):

set DOT_PATH in your doxygen.conf to blank. That works because doxygen will look in your path for.

I installed doxygen with macports, so dot is at /opt/local/bin/dot

Answer (score 1):

For those who call CMake's configure_file() on their Doxfile, an alternative is:

```
DOT_PATH = ${DOXYGEN_DOT_PATH}
```

For me, even though dot's path was in $PATH, the above is the only way I could make it work. Go figure.

Answer (score 1):

The DOT_PATH must be set withing quotes else the paths with whitespaces won't work

```
DOT_PATH = "@DOXYGEN_DOT_PATH@"
```

Comment: Quite obvious after you see it ;) Thanks a bunch!